# how to tell if the two urls are from same domain ( any docs I can follow ? )

Tags: javascript, html, http

```
url1 : http://hello.test.mycomapny.com
url2 : http://test.mycomapny.com
```

Can JS from page loaded by `url1` issue AJAXrequest to resources hosted in `url2`? It seems `url1` is a subdomin of `url2`. I see some website like web.qq.com have similar request (sending request to d.web.qq.com).

Comment: Why some advanced operations when you can actually check by string or cut operations for the two urls?

Comment: I was wondering if page from url1 can send ajax request to url2

Comment: Yes, either with JSONP or CORS.

Comment: What's stopping you from just trying to send the request? If it works it works, if not, handle that in the request callback. Or if you just want to find out if it will work once, try it and see.

Comment: jshanley shhh people would get mad at him for using exceptions/errors to do control flow

Answer (score 2):

http://url.spec.whatwg.org/#api

A nice way to check a URL's domain in modern browsers is to construct a `URL` object, which will parse out the domain.

As for whether you can fetch a resource cross-origin, it's up to the server.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS